# Java android change color in xml file

Tags: java, android

I have this xml where I already set stroke color but I sometimes I want to change stoke color programmatically. The file name is **dummy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

I want to change color (stroke color) programmatically, how I can do this?

I use this xml here :

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/dummy"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/serverStatusWrapper"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_green"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/serverStatus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:antialias="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_input_antenna_white_24dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/locationStatusWrapper"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/shadow_red"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/locationStatus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:antialias="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to create your drawable dynamically i have try this but not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.a);
```

You can change the **stroke** as

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)linearLayout.getBackground();
drawable.setStroke(3, Color.RED);
```

And can change **solid** color as

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)linearLayout.getBackground();
drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok but this xml I use in LinearLayout

Comment: then change imageView to linearlayout

Comment: I try do this but I have nullpointer :              GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)linearLayout.getBackground();

Comment: get the reference for linearlayout, let me edit the answerr

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka i have edited my answer, hope it will work, dont forget to accept the answer and rate it up, if it worked :)

Comment: Glad it worked, please accept the answer so that it may help others in future :)